# Link Not working in image descrption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am working on this site **

> http://webzer.host56.com/

**

the home page gallery has a description area which displays the image description i have added from the meadia image page.in the media image description  field i have added the following

```
<b>Phone:</b> 03 8678 <a href="http://webzer.host56.com/contact-us/" title="Contact Us">1834</a><br>
```

and the attachment page is showing the link **1834** http://webzer.host56.com/?attachment_id=128 in the description. But when i add the image to the gallery in home page it is not showing any link.It is not even showing the 1834 link in source.Please help thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive that your problem is just a simple bug.
When you look at the source code there is following code:

```
<li class="two-dim-item" data-img-desc="<b>Phone:</b> 03 8678 <a href="http://webzer.host56.com/contact-us/" title="Contact Us">1834</a><br>" data-img-width="606" data-img-height="261"><a href=" http://webzer.host56.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/contact.png">contact</a></li>
```

so `data-img-desc=""` has to be closed and `<li>` the right > also...

Greetings

Comment: Please can you explain me what is happening

Comment: You can't use HTML Tags within a Tag. so `data-img-desc="<b>Phone:</b> 03 8678 <a href="http://webzer.host56.com/contact-us/" title="Contact Us">1834</a><br>` is incorrect. So this would be correct: `<li class="two-dim-item" data-img-desc="Phone: 03 8678" data-img-width="606" data-img-height="261">
<a href="http://webzer.host56.com/contact-us/" title="Contact Us" alt="Contact Us"><img src=" http://webzer.host56.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/contact.png"/></a></li>`

Comment: Thank You ... I tried <b>Phone:</b> 03 8678 <a href='http://webzer.host56.com/contact-us/' title='Contact Us'>1834</a><br>  and worked thank you